# Error coming while creating header file for java native method

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I am trying to create header file for java native method in android application for developing JNI interface. I have created native method in java file. and also run the android application. And now I have trying to create header file using javah command like `D:\workspace\Internet_TV4\bin>javah com.internet.videos.Internet_TV4`
then this error is coming

```
error: cannot access com.internet.videos.Internet_TV4
class file for com.internet.videos.Internet_TV4 not found
javadoc: error - Class com.internet.videos.Internet_TV4 not found.
Error: No classes were specified on the command line.  Try -help.
```

where **com.internet.videos** is the package name and **Internet_TV4** is the class name.I have successfully created header file  earlier using this command for sdk older version. Now I am using latest version of android sdk and I am getting such type of error. And In newer version all class file are created in \workspace\Internet_TV4\bin\classes\com\internet\videos  path so I have also tried for that command `D:\workspace\Internet_TV4\bin>javah classes.com.internet.videos.Internet_TV4`
But I am again getting some error like

```
error: cannot access classes.com.internet.videos.Internet_TV4
bad class file: .\classes\com\internet\videos\Internet_TV4.class
class file contains wrong class: com.internet.videos.Internet_TV4
Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpa
th.
com.sun.tools.javac.util.Abort
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Check.completionError(Check.java:164)
        at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocEnv.loadClass(DocEnv.java:149)
        at com.sun.tools.javadoc.RootDocImpl.<init>(RootDocImpl.java:77)
        at com.sun.tools.javadoc.JavadocTool.getRootDocImpl(JavadocTool.java:159
)
        at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.parseAndExecute(Start.java:330)
        at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.begin(Start.java:128)
        at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.execute(Main.java:66)
        at com.sun.tools.javah.Main.main(Main.java:147)
javadoc: error - fatal error
```

So I am not able to create header file. Can any body please help me to solve this problem.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you create your header file manually? The naming conventions for JNI functions are fairly simple. You can have a look at the hello-jni example from NDK.

Comment: I think you are using very old steps for using native codes in Andorid, Why don't you follow Android-NDK steps, its so easy to work with it. this link will help you to begin work with Native codes. http://mindtherobot.com/blog/452/android-beginners-ndk-setup-step-by-step/

Comment: can you check what you had mentioned in the package of the class.

Comment: @Alex thanks for your response.. I have created file manually and solved my problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having this exact same issue and figured it out after running `javah -help`

You need to set the classpath using `-classpath` option. In the folder where you want to output the header file, run:

```
javah -classpath D:\workspace\Internet_TV4\bin\classes\ com.internet.videos.Internet_TV4
```